# Discord.py: Why do the welcome and goodbye messages repeat?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Problem: I am trying to have it so that the bot sends a single message in general, but the messages continuously repeat, seemingly increasing each time this occurs. Also, if I switch the message to something else, the repeated parts are of the old message.

Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ok')



@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel=discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="general")
    await channel.send("Hi {}".format(member))

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel=discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name="general")
    await channel.send("Bye")

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is under the function variable then you have to end each function.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: ```Return False``` at the end of the welcome and goodbye.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to multiple instances of the application are running. Check your task manager and search for python process, End it if there are multiple and re-run the script.